# Can I play a game from the Ubuntu store on Windows?

Tags: games

Does anyone know if it is possible to play a game from the Ubuntu store (or whatever it's called on Ubuntu 16.04) on a windows computer? I have found a very fun game (Red Eclipse) that is not on Windows. I just want to play it on my Windows computer, so that I can use my controller. My controller is a Logitech F310, and I can only get it to work with those kinds of games on Windows.

Comment: In general, no. There's no good way to run Ubuntu games on Windows (some WSL hacks might be possible, but not worth the effort). However, it seems Red Eclipse specifically will work, since it has a Windows version.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [wiki](http://redeclipse.net/wiki/How_to_Install_Red_Eclipse) there is a Windows installer.

Have not tried it myself.

Also
[image]

Comment: Where is that? I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and my store looks nothing like that. I'll try to check it out myself, in case you never go back onto this post.

Comment: That's the old Ubuntu Software Center, I'm still on 14.04  The wiki I linked to in the answer has a download link for the Windows installer, i.e. http://redeclipse.net/download/windows

Answer (score 0):

I have found that many games on the software center were also published with Windows executables (on the developer's website, not the SC.) One such example is Red Eclipse. Others include Battle for Wesnoth, Nexuiz, and Minetest (all of which are great games, by the way.)

I have to agree with Zacharee1. It's not possible to run strictly Linux games on Windows unless you get your hands on the source and can somehow recompile or reverse engineer it.

It's just not worth the effort.

It's just like how many Windows programs cannot run on Ubuntu, whether through Wine or a virtual machine.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need "some WSL hacks " but could run a Linux in VirtualBox on Windows .. there you can run all Linux Programs as usual ... asuming ofcourse your PC is strong enough ;)